# [42601][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1";

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE admin.sp_pm_drop_all_scratch_tables (redshift_table_name IN VARCHAR)
                   LANGUAGE plpgsql
                   as $$
                   DECLARE
                      temp_table_name varchar(100);
                      row record;
                   BEGIN
                      temp_table_name := 'procedure_temp_table';
                      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE if exists '||temp_table_name;
                      EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE '||temp_table_name||' as select * from  nidhi_test.'||redshift_table_name;
                      FOR row IN(
                       select 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '|| schemaname || '."'|| tablename|| '" cascade' as sql_name
                       from pg_tables
                         where schemaname in ('nidhi_scratch')
                         and schemaname || '.'|| tablename not in (select schema_name || '.'|| table_name  from temp_table_name)
                   )
                   LOOP
                   EXECUTE row.sql_name;
                   END LOOP;
                   end;
                   $$ ;
```

i am trying to create this procedure but getting this error[42601][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1";

when i try to run this procedure it gives me the error
[42601][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1";
basically i want to drop the tables from schema nidhi_scratch and not drop tables which are there in temp_table_name
temp_table_name is getting filled from nidhi_test.‘||redshift_table_name
redshift_table_name is a variable getting filled from airflow

Comment: please could you post your code and a question?

Comment: I have pasted the procedure i am trying to run and the error message below